# FTP download - not saving

Tags: python, ftplib

I have a script to download CSV files from a FTP server. 
I have tested the script now several time. And from PyCharm there are coming no Error. It is going trough as "processed". But the problem is that it is not saving/downloading the files. I can find them in my directory.

So I have no feedback in what I am doing wrong. Can anybody help me/ tell me where I am going wrong?

```
from ftplib import FTP
import os


#domain name or server ip:
ftp = FTP('..')
ftp.login(user='..', passwd = '..')

savedir = '/Users/bjorn/documents/test'
os.chdir(savedir)

def grabFile():

    filename = '2018-11-16-inquiries.csv'
    localfile = open(filename, 'wb')
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, localfile.write, 1024)

    print filename, "done"
    ftp.quit()
    localfile.close()
```

Comment: maybe call `grabFile()` ...

Comment: thnx, that was really stupid of me :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the theoretically correct code:

```
from ftplib import FTP import os 
#domain name or server ip: 
ftp = FTP('..')       
ftp.login(user='..', passwd = '..') 
savedir = '/Users/bjorn/documents/test'  
def grabFile(filename):
    localfile = open('Users\\bjorn\\Documents\\test\\' + filename, 'wb')

    ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename,     localfile.write, 1024) 
    print filename, "done" 
    ftp.quit()
    localfile.close()

grabFile('2018-11-16-inquiries.csv')
```

If this doesn't work, have a look at [this tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/ftp-transfers-python-ftplib/)